# Copying cells across workbooks doesn't work like it used to

Tags: excel, vba

I've used the same subroutine in previous macros and it worked fine but now it simply won't work.

```
Public inputFile, outputFile as Worksheet

sub copy()

    Set inputFile = excel.Workbooks.Open(get_file(".xlsb", fullpath:=True))
    Set outputFile = Workbooks("Sales_Report.xlsm")


    inputFile.Sheets("Planilha1").Activate 'error: Method or data member not found (highlights ".Sheets")
    inputFile.Sheets("Planilha1").Cells.Select
    inputFile.Sheets("Planilha1").Cells.Copy

    outputFile.Sheets("Vales").Activate  
    outputFile.Sheets("Vales").Select.Cells
    Selection.Clear
    outputFile.Sheets("Vales").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

end sub
```

As soon as I run the macro the error diplayed is: Method or data member not found and then it highlights the `Sheets` method.
I tried changing it to `inputfile.Worksheets("Vales")` and make the variables not public but still didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the **exact, complete error message** in your post. Also indicate which specific line it is, because you have three places where it refers to `inputFile.Sheets`, so saying *it highlights the `Sheets` method isn't helpful. Also see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/62576)

Comment: You can just use `Workbooks.Open` in your code. You need to check if your `inputFile` was actually found, and thus opened, before proceeding. That depends on whatever is in `get_file` really. You could try `If intputFile is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

Comment: What is `outputFile.Sheets("Vales").Select.Cells`? Did you swap the `Select` and `Cells` in the question by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

```
Public inputFile, outputFile as Worksheet          '<-- WORKSHEET

Set outputFile = Workbooks("Sales_Report.xlsm")    '<-- WORKBOOK
```

You have mismatched variable types here. Notice `OutputFile` is declared as a `Worksheet` and inside your macro you assigned this variable to a `Workbook`

Since this is a worksheet variable, objects such as `Sheets` are not available hence your error.

---

### *Side Note*

Your public variable decliration is probably not working the way you think it is. Variable types need to be assigned one by one (*sigh*). In your statement you actually declared variables like so:

```
inputFile = Variant
outputFile = Worksheet
```

but I expect that you actually want

```
Public inputFile as Workbook, outputFile as Workbook
```

Comment: Nice catch. :-)